# Why this regular expression matches /\w+[^(]/?

Tags: ruby, regex

```
>> 'hola(' =~ /\w+[^(]/
=> 0
>> $&
=> "hola"
```

As far as I know, `/\w+[^(]/` should match a word not followed by a `(`. I also tried with `negative look-behind` and escaping the `(`; with the same results.

What I find estrange about this, is that if I try with `/a[^(]/`, it works (as expected).

```
>> 'hola(' =~ /a[^(]/
=> nil
```

So it definitely has something to do with the `+` quantifier.

What's happening?

I tried using `Ruby 2.2` and `Python 3.3`

Comment: `\w+` matches "hol", and `[^(]` matches "a".

Comment: [String#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) merely tells you if there is a match (and if there is one, where it starts). Here you are better off finding *what* is matched, if there is a match. For that, use [String#[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) (or [String#match](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-match)) with a regex: `'hola('[/\w+[^(]/] #=> "hola"`.  This leads you to @Chris' explanation. You will get the result you want by adding beginning and ending of string anchors to your regex: `'hola('[/^\w+[^(]$/] #=> nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `\w+[^(]` matches one or more word-characters, followed by any character that isn't a `(`.
Which means it will match `hola` and ignore the last character.

Depending on where you want to use this, a pattern like `\w+\b(?!\()` might be more suitable, as it will match any word not followed by `(`.

Answer (score 4):

The `hol` portion matches the `\w+` portion of the expression, and the `[^(]` portion matches `a`. The `(` part of the input is ignored.

Add `$` to fix the problem:

```
>> 'hola(' =~ /\w+[^(]$/
=> nil
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. This kind of errors always bite me :(, very naive from my part.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, the regex engine works like this: scan down to `hola` which matches `\w+` part, but the next character `(` doesn't match `[^(]`, then does **backtracking**, and find out that it matches when `hol` to `\w+` part, and `a` matches `[^(]` part.

---

You can inhibit the backtracking by using `(?>re)` for an independent regex engine:

```
'hola(' =~ /(?>\w+)[^(]/
# => nil
```

or `++` repetition for **possessive**:

```
'hola(' =~ /\w++[^(]/
# => nil
```

Both are Ruby `Regexp` extensions.

Comment: I was planning to use Thorbear suggestion, but this one seems better.

Comment: sigh, Ruby only :(. I really like this answer, but I may end up using other regex engines in the future.